# Groups which are only defined up to conjugation

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras

I'm trying to understand what the right way is to think about "groups which are only well-defined up to conjugation."  Since this is somewhat vague let me clarify it by pointing out the main examples I have in mind:

"The" absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ which depends on a choice of algebraic closure and so is only well-defined up to conjugation.  Here the usual approach is to study finite dimnesional representations of this group, since the isomorphism class of the representation is a conjugation invariant.

The (outer) automorphism group of "the" hyperfinite $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor.  Again this depends on a choice of hyperfinite $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor, and so is only well-defined up to conjugation.  This group is simple, so the kinds of techniques you use to study the absolute Galois group won't work.

As pointed out in comments, and in email by Qiaochu, one way to think about these examples is that instead of a group you have a connected groupoid.  If you pick a basepoint a connected groupoid gives a group, but without picking a basepoint you have something somewhat different from a group.

But these two examples have something additional in common which is that one doesn't have easy direct access to the points.  Or even if you do find a particular way to write down a base point, there are many natural choices of basepoint and there's no constructive way to write down the path between basepoints.

Is there a good way to think or talk about this which will make more concrete the intuiton that you're banning yourself from ever fixing basepoints or fixing a path between two points?

(The original version of this question was NARQ, so I've edited and rewritten it to try to improve it.)

Comment: Analogous to the Galois group are fundamental groups, which depend on the choice of base point. Again, one might study them via deck transformations, or via their representations (which are equivalent to local systems). (The analogue is due to the étale fundamental group, which is the absolute Galois group in the case of a field, and which is the profinite completion of the fundamental group of $X(\mathbb{C})$, when $X$ is a smooth projective $\mathbb{C}$-scheme.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intent of the question. By "group", we usually mean an isomorphism class of groups anyway.

Comment: @Geoff: I'm a bit confused by the question too, but I'm even more confused by your comment. Any algebra textbook defines a group as a set endowed with a group law, not modulo equivalence. When I think of a group such as $GL_3(\widehat{\mathbf{Q}_p})$ I may know that it's abstractly isomorphic to $GL_3(\mathbf{C})$ but I would certainly not consider them as the same. Idem with $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a group which *isn't* an example of this phenomenon.  To talk about the symmetry group of 'the' cube we have to choose a cube...  With @GeoffRobinson, I really don't see what this question is getting at.

Comment: Groupoids might help you clarify your thinking about this.

Comment: Fair enough, this may be NARQ. I remember though when I learned about Galois representations that a big deal was made about how you have to look at Galois representations *because* that's something invariant under conjugation, unlike other properties.  Perhaps the point is that for these examples you need choice to build it in the first place so you can't just agree before hand on what you mean. Unlike with the cube where we can just agree.

Comment: I think "groupoid" is a pretty good answer. Do you have any examples that are not groupoids, where the indeterminacy is for a reason other than choosing which of many isomorphic objects to take the automorphism group? (the vna example is a little more involved, but the key indeterminacy is exactly this.)

Comment: After your edit, I would say that in the case of Galois groups, the étale fundamental groupoid is the object you are looking for. See Deligne's “Le groupe fondamental de la droite projective moins trois points” (http://publications.ias.edu/node/407). It is a groupoid internal to the category of lisse $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-sheaves (if memory serves me right). You never have to choose a basepoint, it is concrete, but it requires a fair bit of abstraction to define this object.

Comment: I think there are two issues: (1) having base points but not having a single preferred one, and (2) not having access to any base points without the axiom of choice. As many have mentioned, issue #1 can be handled well using groupoids. For issue #2, you probably want to use the category of all actions of your groupoid on sets, which can typically be defined without mentioning any points or even requiring their existence. For instance, for a field $K$, the category of sheaves of sets on the etale topology of $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ is...

Comment: ...canonically equivalent to $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$-sets for any choice of separable closure $\bar{K}$ but involves no choice. Similarly with reps of $\pi_1$ and locally constant sheaves. Then linear representations of your Galois group / fundamental group are just vector-space objects in your category of actions of your (nonexistent) groupoid on sets. In fact, this category will be a topos, so you can work with it as easily as with the category of sets, as long as you use only allowable syntax (replace existential quantifiers with local existential quantifiers, etc).

Answer (score 10):

For reference, here's roughly the content of the email I sent to Noah:

The short answer is "connected groupoids, regarded as objects in the homotopy category of groupoids."

Recall that the category of groupoids is really a $2$-category: it has objects groupoids, morphisms functors, and $2$-morphisms natural transformations. The homotopy category of groupoids, $\text{Ho}(\text{Gpd})$, is the category whose objects are groupoids and whose morphisms are natural isomorphism classes of functors. Concretely, there's a subcategory given by one-object groupoids, which are groups, and morphisms between these are pointwise conjugacy classes of group homomorphisms (so in particular it's morphisms, not groups, that we're only regarding as well-defined up to conjugacy, but as category theorists we know that it's the morphisms that are important anyway). For example, in this category

- $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, G)$ returns the conjugacy classes, rather than the elements, of $G$.
- $\text{Aut}(G)$ returns the outer automorphism group of $G$.

This category is an algebraic model of what happens when you try to get a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces to induce a map on fundamental groups: to do this you need to pick a basepoint $x \in X$ so that you get a map $\pi_1(X, x) \to \pi_1(Y, f(x))$, and the homomorphism you get by varying the basepoint along a path depends on the homotopy class of the path, unless you only work up to conjugacy. More precisely, the homotopy category of $1$-types is equivalent to the homotopy category of groupoids, with the equivalence given by taking the fundamental groupoid. (To get the ordinary category of groups we need to use pointed connected $1$-types.)

In the case of Galois theory, the connected groupoid in question is the groupoid whose objects are the algebraic closures of a field and whose morphisms are isomorphisms between these, just as in the topological case the fundamental groupoid is the groupoid whose objects are the points of a space and whose morphisms are homotopy classes of paths between these.

---

The case of Galois theory exhibits the difficulty Noah talks about in the edit if we don't allow ourselves enough choice to construct algebraic closures. In this case I think the correct replacement of, say, $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is the category of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. The "absolute Galois groupoid" can be recovered from this category via Grothendieck's Galois theory, as the groupoid whose objects are fiber functors and whose morphisms are natural isomorphisms, but I think it takes some choice to write down fiber functors as well so one can just refrain from doing so and do other stuff instead.

In particular, it should be possible to write down, say, $\text{Rep}(\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}))$ from the above data without ever explicitly constructing the group itself. (Analogy: I can write down the category of local systems on a space $X$ with values in $\text{Vect}$ without choosing a basepoint for $X$. It should in fact be possible to describe what a local system on a locale ought to be, even if the locale has no points! Perhaps this is the sort of thing you want.)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the opposite of the category of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, equipped with the "atomic" topology, is a site for the topos of "continuous" $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} | \mathbb{Q})$-sets. (One identifies the representable sheaves with the sets with exactly one orbit.) In particular one can define Galois representations to be internal $k$-vector spaces in this topos. It should also be possible to construct a localic groupoid incarnation of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} | \mathbb{Q})$ without choice, using the Joyal–Tierney theory.

Comment: I was also going to suggest localic groupoids, but would then point out that just as you can encode the conjugations of the group in the groupoid, so you can also encode the homotopies in the model so perhaps Noah needs some sort of infinity groupoid model of the setting from the start then collasing back down to something more usual once it is clear what part of it is needed at any given stage.

Comment: Regarding the paragraph on fundamental groups: I think it would be more accurate to say that you need a distinguished basepoint to even *define* a fundamental group.  Otherwise, you have $\pi_0$ on the free loop space, which is just the sort of floppy object that is under discussion.

Comment: Another idea, to avoid the difficulty that Scott mentions, would be to use more of a Grothendieck SGA1 /  Galois theoretic approach to defining the fundamental groupoid (this replaces points by 'fibre functors', so geometric points in a sheaf theoretic setting). The fundamental groupoid then is a clissfying object classifying certain families of coverings of the space. As a universal object it is only defined up to isomorphism, but the property determines it more fully than choosing a base point. This seems nearer to Noah's orginal problem.

Comment: @Tim: I mentioned this above but I think the problem with replacing points with fiber functors is that it can still be hard to explicitly write down or work with fiber functors. I think working directly with the category of coverings is the most constructive option.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I agree with you in the main, but would mention the use of van Kampen theorem type arguments, at the covering space level, (so Artin gluing I suppose?). I feel that the best way forward theoretically would be to develop an $\infty$-category approach (e.g. look for a natural quasi-category in the context)and then to examine the indeterminacy and the structure of the fillers in the simplicial classes.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can say something about why this problem rears its head particularly in the study of $\operatorname{Gal}( \overline{\mathbb Q}|\mathbb Q)$. As Qiaochu and others have pointed out, a group-up-to-conjugation is more or less a connected groupoid, and this interpretation meets up with the topological intuition. As HJRW points out, the fact that the Galois group appears to us as a groupoid does not distinguish it much from other symmetry groups. Those are naturally groupoids, and we must fix a basepoint to speak of elements of the group.

Note also that there is no difficulty in fixing a basepoint of the Galois goup! Simply take the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ inside $\mathbb C$. Grothendieck's dessins d'enfants are essentially a way of studying the Galois group via this basepoint.

Instead, I think a key problem is that there is more than one good way of choosing the basepoint. It might be better to work with a more general notion of a basepoint. A basepoint is a functor from the one-object one-morphism category to the groupoid. More generally, we can consider functors from an arbitrary category to the groupoid.

For each prime $p$, we have a functor from the groupoid of algebraic closures of $\mathbb Q_p$ to the groupoid of algebraic closures of $\mathbb Q$ - just take all the algebraic elements. Since the Galois group of $\mathbb Q_p$ is not so hard to understand (a least compared to the Galois group of $\mathbb Q$), having one of these is a lot like having a basepoint.

Why is this problematic? Because different phenomena are most naturally studied using different basepoints. Remember that, inverse Galois problem aside, we mostly don't study the Galois group as an abstract group. Instead, we study how it relates to other things we care about: Number fields are subgroups of the Galois group, but more importantly,  we can relate that subgroup to the arithmetic of that number field. Almost everywhere a Galois group appears in number theory, it's being related to lots of other interesting things. These interesting things usually have aspects that only make sense at a given place. So to study the Galois group, we really need to study it at each place idependently. While these different basepoints exist perfectly constructively, the paths between them do not, and these paths are crucial to get an understanding of the Galois group.

So I think there is no mathematical difference with the group of symmetries of the cube, but a metamathematical difference. I know nothing about von Neumann algebras, but I would be interested to hear if there is a similar picture for the hyperfinite $\operatorname{II}_1$ factor.

Finally, note that one reason Galois representations are so important is that we have a good tool for constructing Galois representations, that being etale cohomology of algebraic varieties. This is why we consider Galois representations over $\mathbb Q_l$, rather than another field. We also have powerful tools like L-functions and automorphic forms for describing properties of Galois representations. These all make Galois representations a fruitful field, whereas dessin d'enfants has not been so fruitful because there are not so many powerful tools - but there is nothing intrinsic about the origin of the Galois group that forces it to be that way. Maybe we just haven't discovered the right tools yet!

Comment: Could you please write what you wanted to say in "Number fields are subgroups of the Galois group"? I am aware that this was six years ago, but the answer itself is certainly still valuable and useful one, so...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I was just referring to the Galois correspondence between number fields and open subgroups of the absolute Galois group (the fundamental theorem of Galois theory). Should I say more?

Comment: But the statement as written,  "Number fields are subgroups of the Galois group" simply does not typecheck, does it? I mean, a field is not a group

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Correct, it doesn't typecheck.